# PHP COM CÂMERA DO ANDROID

Tags: php, android

como faço para utilizar a câmera do celular (Android) com PHP, atualmente utilizo com PHP+JAVASCRIPT, alguém poderia me mandar uma ajuda e se possível algum exemplo.

Obrigado

Comment: Olá @Marcel, para que possamos ajudar você com sua dúvida, recomendamos que você explique o seu problema de modo claro, informando também o que você já tentou fazer para resolver o seu problema. Fornecer códigos também é importante, para saber como você está trabalhando e o que pode ser melhorado/resolvido. Recomendo que você reveja esses pontos e melhore sua pergunta. Bom desenvolvimento.

Comment: De uma olhada neste tópico em que se tem a mesma dúvida que você: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469782/can-an-html5-javascript-android-app-access-the-camera-voice-recorder  Pelo que disseram, não há como fazer isso sem utilizar algum Framework.

Comment: Hoje tenho um programa em php que utiliza javascrip utilizando a webcam para tirar fotos, pois bem, qdo executo esse programa no celular ou tablet, o programa não reconhece a câmera do celular ou do tablet com reconhece a webcam no computador, acredito que dispensa colocar parte do programa, pois tenho a impressão que é algo relacionado ao php acessar a câmera do celular que tem o OS Android.

Answer (score 1):

Com php você não vai conseguir acessar nenhum recurso do hardware, dependendo do seu objetivo você pode criar um backend em PHP que irá fornecer alguns recursos via REST e no aparelho cliente deve ter uma aplicação android(java) ou híbrida(javascript) para consumir seu REST e acessar os recursos da camera como desejar. 
Tome como ponto de partida esse [link do projeto cordova](https://cordova.apache.org) você irá entender melhor o seu problema.